# How to restart an exited Docker container as an interactive bash session using a container ID?

Tags: docker

How do I restart an exited Docker container as an interactive bash session using its container ID?

Suppose...

```
sudo docker start -p 80:80 -t -i linode/lamp /bin/bash
```

Gets me into a bash session.  I did some stuff to the container and exited and now I need to go back into as an interactive bash session, not a background one.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  In the terminal:

```
docker exec -it <container_ID> bash
```